# How to make super key only show Chrome window in current workspace in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I am switching from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18. One thing I am confused about Ubuntu 18 is that: When I press <kbd>Super</kbd> key, it shows all the apps from all the workspace. That makes me hard to find what I want since workspace should be separated.

Anyone knows how to make <kbd>Super</kbd> key only show apps in the current workspace?

example screenshots:

workspace 1:
[image]

workspace 2:
[image]

super key view:
[image]

The weird thing is:

For other apps, terminal in workspace1 and vscode in workspace2, they only appear in their workspace using <kbd>Super</kbd> key;
However, for Chrome in both workspaces, <kbd>Super</kbd> key will display all the windows of that app.
This is not the same in Ubuntu 16.

So I guess this is a Chrome problem instead of GNOME?

This is pretty important to me since I would open A LOT OF chrome tabs when working, each window will only have tabs on a particular topic.

Comment: hi pomsky, I am using original Ubuntu 18, I heard it changed from unity to gnome.

Comment: @pomsky I just updated the question, seems for separate apps it is okay.

Comment: @pomsky seems only happens for Chrome...

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors? I think that may be the root of the problem.

Comment: @pomsky I do have multiple monitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnome Shell Extension [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) solves everything!

Thanks

Comment: There's are additional settings using which we can disable Top bar on all monitors after activating the plugin